# Magento Worldpay Integration - "Error Occurred"

Tags: php, magento, worldpay

I am experiencing the following error with a Worldpay integration in Magento:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/236952/

The transaction works from Magento to Worldpay completely fine and payments go through successfully. The problem occurs after a transaction, when returning to the site. The customer receives an email from Worldpay but the information is not transferred back to Magento. Transaction statuses are displayed as "Payment Pending". Worldpay takes us back to Magento but we receive a message just saying "Error Occurred" briefly before being taken to an empty basket.

Has anyone encountered this problem and successfully managed to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In form posted to worldpay there is a callback URL.

Check if value is correct or not.

Also in your Worldpay account configuration make sure payment response is enabled.

Once you have done this place some log code or check debug log of world on Magento.
This will ensure response reaching or not.
Once response is reaching your site you can debug further to make out where the issue is.

I feel that its the response not reaching(being posted) your site.

Comment: Hi Satish, thank you very much for your response, I will be able to try your suggestions tomorrow and post back with my results.

Comment: I just fixed one worldpay site issues and what I have posted in My response was the reason for that site issue.

Comment: Hi Satish, after discussing the issue with Worldpay they believe the problem is that our Magento installation is out of date. I have returned to the client who will be looking to update their version of Magento in the new year. Thank you for your thoughts but unfortunately they haven't solved our issue. Hopefully updating the version of Magento will sort everything out. Worldpay mentioned something about old version of Magento not allowing communication between itself and the new Worldpay servers.

Comment: which Magento Version you have?

Answer (score 0):

In the Phoenix Worldpay extension there is a debugging system built in, you need to go to System->Configuration->Payment Methods

Then in the WorldPay section at the bottom is an option to enable debugging.

Once this is enabled, debug information will be logged var/log/payment_worldpay_cc.log